# MongoDB aggregation - choose a lookup collection depending on the data. Can it be done?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have one collection - "items"

I also have two other collections - "books_details" & "fruits_details". They have different structures.

Some items are item_type:book and some are item_type:fruit.

Each item has an item_type_id that matches a document in the corresponding collection.

I want to display a combined list of items with the details from the corresponding collection, depending on the item_type.

It seems like :

- I need to do two different $lookup stages and combine them. Didn't succeed doing this.

or

- Make one $lookup and make the results the basis for the second $lookup stage  and combine them. Didn't succeed doing this.

or

- I need to do the $lookup depending on the item_type. Didn't find a way to do this.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Thanks.

**items**

```
{
  "item_id": 1234,
  "item_type": "book",
  "item_type_id": 1
},
{
  "item_id": 5678,
  "item_type": "fruit",
  "item_type_id": 1
}
```

**books_details**

```
{
  "item_id": 1,
  "title": "Gone with the wind",
  "author": "Margaret Mitchell"
}
```

**fruits_details**

```
{
  "item_id": 1,
  "name": "Banana",
  "color": "yellow"
}
```

**expected list**

```
{
      "item_id": 1234,
      "item_type": "book",
      "item_type_id": 1,
      "fruits_details": {},
      "books_details": {"title": "Gone with the wind", "author": "Margaret Mitchell"}
    },
    {
      "item_id": 5678,
      "item_type": "fruit",
      "item_type_id": 1,
      "fruits_details": {"name":"Banana","color":"yellow"},
      "books_details": {}
    }
```

Comment: Don't try to build a relational database with NoSQL, unless you have a strong reason. I advise you to store *everything* in one collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below [**`aggregation`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e_7zDQ7BJ0B)

```
db.items.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "fruits",
    "localField": "item_type_id",
    "foreignField": "item_id",
    "as": "fruits_details"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "books",
    "localField": "item_type_id",
    "foreignField": "item_id",
    "as": "books_details"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "books_details": {
      "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$item_type", "book"] }, "$books_details", {}]
    },
    "fruits_details": {
      "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$item_type", "fruit"] }, "$fruits_details", {}]
    }
  }}
])
```